# How to replace lambda delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

(removed unnecessary clutter)

**Edit 1**

Seems that my questions are not very clear... doh... :)

So ....

How to write this:

```
instance.Method(e => OtherClass.Fill(e, instance2.A, instance3.B));
```

with something like this:

```
instance.Method(new Action<IDataReader>(OtherClass.Fill));
```

When "Method" signature is:

```
void Method(Action<IDataReader> reader)
```

and "Fill" signature is:

```
void Fill(IDataReader reader, string a, string b);
```

**Update**

I figured out one alternative implementation, but it still causes debugger to step in to that Fill call. There's no anymore lambda notation but it still seems to step in, argh...

```
instance.Method(delegate(IDataReader e) { OtherClass.Fill(e, instance2.A, instance3.B); });
```

**Solution**

Seems that I just need one additional method which is called from delegate and that method then passes call to next method (Fill) with two more parameters:

```
instance.Method(this.Foo);

[DebuggerStepThrough()]
private void Foo(IDataReader reader)
{
    OtherClass.Fill(reader, this.instance2.A, this.instance3.B)
}
```

Comment: you have to define the extra params in some way, why can't you use the solution you gave: instance.Method(e => this.Fill(e, instance2.A, instance3.B));?

Comment: Of course I _can_ use it but I wan't to get rid of that debugger will step into that lambda call when using F11 stepping. Quite annoying to debug code and always step into those lambda calls... Because I can write it using lambda notation, I should be able to write it without lambda ;)

Comment: @Harza then hit F10, it will step over it.

Comment: Not helping because in that point I have already ended up to that lambda call. And if lambda is called from loop, hitting F10 will also jump out from loop. Code is quite "large" and I don't "see" what way I end up to that delegate so I can't just think "ok hit F10 because next is that lambda call"

Comment: Doh, sorry for wrong comment, hitting F10 in lambda does not jump out from loop (tested that). Problem here is still that I have already ended up to that lambda anyway and I try to get rid of that.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, somewhere your code must pass those extra parameters, and your debugging experience will walk over that process. The best I can offer you is to wrap the parameter passing a little.

Either:

```
Action<IDataReader> wrapper = reader => this.Fill(reader, instance2.A, instance3.B);
instance.Method(wrapper);
```

or:

```
Func<Action<IDataReader, string, string>, Action<IDataReader>> reducer = arity3 => reader => arity3(reader, instance2.A, instance3.B);
instance.Method(reducer(this.Fill));
```

But obviously, either solution is still going to have the debugger 'walk' over the code. You can't pass parameters without actually *passing* the  parameters.

Comment: Please, check my update. I also planned some kind of "wrapper" but there is still those lambda notations that causes debugger to stepping in, so no help...

Comment: yes, there is no way to pass parameters to your Fill method without having code that actually passes the parameters. Where would you prefer this "event" takes place?

Comment: I solved this just by one additional method. Easy as that. I just tried to fit everything into one line of code :)